# Get tags for each post (wordpress php)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, post, tags

I am using the following code to get the tags of each post (in a grid )

```
<?php 
global $post;
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag) {
    
$tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag'>{$tag->slug}</a>&nbsp;";
 echo $html;
   }
?>
```

It is working, but tags are being repeated. Some of them twice, others three times.
Any idea of how I can fix this code? I don't want to have three times the same tags for the same post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will work you can further style it by adding classes directly to it. If its still getting repeated check the tags taxonomy to see if it getting repeated there.

```
<?php
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $tag->name; ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I though a variable was missing in my code (but your code works perfectly / I did a small change to echo the slug like I had done in my code, and it is working. Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: Don't forget to wp_reset_post_data.